# Scheduled notifications don't appear

Tags: android, notifications, schedule

I'm developing my first Android app, Todo List, and i have to schedule notification at custom date(in 24 hr format) & time with date & timepicker.

Notifications don't appear as scheduled !

Can someone tell me what is the problem with my code?

My code :
Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.todo.amine.mytodo"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyAlarm"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            </receiver>
        </application>

        </manifest>
```

CreateNotify Method :

```
     public void createNotify(int month, int year, int day, int hour, int m){

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date temp = c.getTime();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       /** calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);**/
        Date pm = calendar.getTime();

        if(pm.after(temp))
        {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, MyReceiver.class);
         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

    }
```

MyAlarm.class

```
     import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;


    public class MyAlarm extends Service
    {

        private NotificationManager mManager;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);



   mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Main.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_appxhdpi,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), `"AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);`

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    }
```

MyReceive.class

```
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
            context.startService(service1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error or problem you have with this code?

Comment: notifications dont appear

Comment: Please add a more details to your question by editing it and change your title to reflect that. As of now it looks like you want someone to write code for you to schedule notifications.

Comment: debugging 101: a/ is your service called. b/ if no, is your receiver called. c/ if no, is createNotify method called. d/ ...